# Editing tags not allowed because not 6 characters?

Tags: support, status-norepro, editing, tags, retagging

I was trying to edit the post "[Big Bang Anybody?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/28984/big-bang-anybody?lq=1)" by adding a [popular-science](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/popular-science) tag to it.. While until now, even if I didn't edit the body of the post, I could still edit the tags. However, it seems like from today onwards, to edit the tags, I also need to add 6 characters to the text! At  first,  I thought of simply adding the followsing text:

```
$$\mbox{ }$$
```

However, I realised that then the edit would be rejected (since it is too trivial) and so will the tag edits .

So, why do we need to modify the text body just to edit the tags?

Comment: Strange, I could do it. I mean just attaching the tag and do nothing else. Maybe something has changed only for edits of people who have not yet 2000 rep ?

Comment: @Dilaton: I tried a few tests on the post and it is working again. I don't know what had gone wrong...