# Edits must be 6 characters long

Tags: feature-request

Previously the question concerning edits of 6 characters was asked [Editing tags not allowed because not 6 characters?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4478/editing-tags-not-allowed-because-not-6-characters), however the answers provided were not satisfactory for the question. It is often the case that a single sign needs to be changed or a trivial typo disrupts the flow. In addition some edits are made in series as the question/answer are read over.

Specifically I am writing to make a change to the page [How does the Higgs mechanism work?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/17944/how-does-the-higgs-mechanism-work/17964#17964). My concern is an edit of lambda squared to lambda in the Lagrangian under the header putting it all together. This matches the quartic interaction as typically written and correspondingly as the potential as defined above.

Comment: In practice there is always something else that can be improved in a post. Improvise! E.g. in the current case (if one is just looking for a minimal thing to improve, short of just adding a hidden string ${}{}{}{}$), one could add a full stop at the end of each of the displayed equations.

Comment: @Qmechanic not all answers or questions contain mathematics. Sometimes the edit is just a typo. This error cannot be changed and leaves the question/answer with error. It is understandable that such trivial errors will cause an exorbitant amount of work to approve.

Comment: Consider the case of someone who has approved edits coming back for further edits. Maybe the 6 character restriction need not hold for them.

Comment: High-rep users can make any edit without restriction.  Until you have the rep, there is always something else you can find to make it 6 chars.

Comment: @BrandonEnright I know, `6char` at the bottom.